# Is there a process for reporting or otherwise dealing with malicious downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes

The automated software doesn't seem to catch them if they happen gradually:

> [image]

Comment: How do you know the votes are malicious?

Comment: @RalZarek This is not serial voting (or at least there is no evidence of it).

Comment: Well, looking at his record (which is otherwise almost downvote-free) I'd tend to give him the benefit of the doubt. It may not be possible to reverse these though. A mod *may* be able to do something about it if the votes are all from the same person

Comment: I guess this Meta post will do it, but you can just flag one of your posts for moderator attention using the "other" option to explain what's going on. It's no guarantee that you'll get your rep back (you most likely won't), but they might take a deeper look.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, I found that recommendation elsewhere and just followed it.

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384918/can-a-struct-alias-its-own-initial-and-only-member/17385083#17385083) *All answers downvoted* [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341662/text-file-not-oppening-in-c/17341722#17341722) *Answer contains a question/clarification* [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012707/initialization-global-and-static-variable-to-0-is-always-unnecessary/17013215#17013215) *All answers downvoted* [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665995/c-how-to-modify-memory-of-structs-that-are-inside-other-structs/16666234#16666234) Possibly malicious vote

Comment: I dont think its malicious at all[*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186962/is-there-a-process-for-reporting-or-otherwise-dealing-with-malicious-downvotes#comment574086_186962). If it is, then it is not targeted at you in particular.

Comment: @AsheeshR And I think you're mistaken ... as @ Pekka 웃 noted, there's an unusual pattern. I posted this because, when my rep dropped 2 points yesterday, I found myself expecting it to drop 2 today, and it did. And your claim about 1 is incorrect -- ouah's answer was not downvoted. The pattern you are seeing is less salient than the one I am. Anyway, it's somewhat moot as flagging my answer seems to be the best way to report it and I'm not interested in a debate about whether it's malicious.

Comment: Feel free to flag and report it to the Moderators. Also, in the future, continue to post on Meta about any weird voting patterns that you may come across. I did not mean to discourage or disparage you in any way. All I am saying is that, you do not have a strong case this time around.

Comment: Here's the latest: -2  1 hour ago  downvote  C pointers to pointers, characters ... downvote of an answer from October.

Comment: @AsheeshR Today's capricious/malicious downvote: -2 How is {int i=999; char c=i;} different from {char c=999;}?

Comment: Did you have an argument with anyone on Jun 29th? The voting is certainly weird, but I dont think its actionable. Have you flagged for Mod attention explaining the issue?

Comment: @AsheeshR Yes, glad you agree, apparently not, yes. I'll try that again if this goes on for another couple of weeks ...

Comment: Here we go again: -2 downvote  Printing pointer to pointer

Comment: And again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548647/how-to-convert-uint16-t2n-to-uint32-tn-effectively/17549235#17549235

Comment: And on it goes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17539990/544557 ... no detectable action by moderators, despite several flags linking to this question.